# Mapbox DIrection API : inversion between walking and cycling

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-api-directions

Hello 
 on a service which uses the Mapbox Direction API (in France), I noticed a problem. There is an inversion between the results offered for walking and cycling directions : they are reversed.
I thought it was a reversal in the implementation of mapbox API. To better understand the problem, I tested directly on the mapbox page (https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/directions/) and in fact it seems to be a problem at the level of the API itself : in any case on French territory, the results of walking and cycling are swapped ... thank you in advance for taking my request into consideration.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Could you expand your question with an actual request that does not produce the expected result?

One reason for the confusion may be that the `biking` profile can return walking instructions in cases where you are not allowed to bike due to restrictions.